# Would it be imbalanced to allow these melee-enhancing cantrips to be used with ranged attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, house-rules, ranged-attack, cantrips

The *green-flame blade* and *booming blade* cantrips both use the following wording:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon

I was wondering what the balance implications are for allowing these spells to be used with ranged weapons.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Almost definitely imbalanced

Both of those options still require the caster/attacker to get within melee range. There's a cost risk for using this. Allowing ranged attacks with them removes that cost and vastly increases their power.

Additionally, *Booming blade* triggers off of movement, so being able to use that ranged will almost always guarantee a trigger as the enemy closes. This is opposed to a melee use where the caster would have to either stay in range, use some sort of mechanic to move away safely, or risk the opportunity attack in moving away.